# WebView API 28 не работает

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть WebView который подгружает локальный (хранящийся в память приложения) файл index.html

```
web.loadUrl("file://" + getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/index.html");
```

внутри этого html подключается обычные js скрипты, которые тянут данные из интернета.

на API 26 все работает отлично.
НО!
когда я меняю targetSdkVersion на 28 ничего не происходит. данные из интернета просто не подключаются.

в чем проблема?

Comment: нужно больше подробностей

Comment: @StrangerintheQ так это все подробности!)) я сам не понимаю, что происходит, куда посмотреть, что еще скинуть. знаю лишь как только меняю targetSdkVersion с 26 на 28 что-то ломается.

Comment: нужно смотреть как получаются данные, которые после изменения не получаются

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это тайловая растровая карта загружаемая через библиотеку Leaflet

Comment: не скачиваются картинки или не работает leaflet в целом?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ похоже что проблема именно в картинках. т.к. панель управления картой (которая тянется из инета через локальный leaflet.js) есть. двигаться по карте я могу (меняются координаты). а вот самих тайлов нету - что и есть странно.

Comment: я правильно понял что js и css от leaflet у Вас локальные?

Comment: Вы можете узнать уходят запросы или нет?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, все верно.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, не могу.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Comment: или поставьте локальный прокси у себя на компьютере и попробуйте понять есть ли запросы через него

Comment: @StrangerintheQ огромное вам спасибо! сейчас сделаю ответ тут, что я нашел. а вы, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, тоже напишите ответ, чтобы я поставил вам лайк и пометил, что это вы решили.

Comment: Это не так важно, главное что Вы справились, если Вам так угодно можете почитать другое мое творчество тут и если что-то покажется Вам интересным поставить плюс =)

Comment: тем более что я ничего не решил, я даже никогда под `android WebView` ни строчки кода не написал, однако  такой же способ отдадки используется не только тут, а например еще на `javafx`, `qt` и в целом везде где используется движок `chromium` в качестве `WebView`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ все ровно! я создаю топики исключительно в тех случаях, когда уже 10-я стр гугла не помогает =) а ваша ссылка помогла в считанные минуты найти причину и пофиксить ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Современный `Android WebView` как и многие другие `VebWiew` во всяких фреймворках вроде `JavaFx` или `Qt` используют в качестве движка `chromium`.

---

Вот ссылки на официальную документацию, как можно удаленно при помощи десктопного хрома отлаживать такие штуковины :)

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

---

PS: уж простите но я не стал это переводить и писать в тексте сообщения. В двух словах - надо включить `RemoteDebugging` в десктопном хроме, `USB отладку` на андроиде и соединить устройства кабелем. После этого в десктопном хроме можно будет увидеть в отладчике то, что происходит на девайсе.

Answer (score 3):

Огромное спасибо [Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q) за помощь и вот, что нашлось:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

с помощью этого метода я выяснил что у меня в WebView вылетает ошибка `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED`

а она в свою очередь решается через `AndroidManifest.xml` добавлением строки:

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ....>
```

Погуглив я нашел следующую информацию (поправьте меня, если я понял что-то не так!):

В Android 8  и выше эту функцию отключили (т.е. раньше она всегда была `true`, а теперь по умолчанию `false`)

Эта функция отвечает за подключение к HTTP ресурсам. Значит, чтобы получать данные или просто отобразить сайт в WebView надо просто прописать это в Манифесте. (странно, что это не permission)

для HTTPS сайтов этого не требуется.

все верно?